# Key to maxima of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, "scores", of integers and I want to find the key(s) of the highest value. I used this code:

```
key = max(scores, key=scores.get)
```

however, this only gives back one key. How does this deal with ties in highest value? I only get one number back. Which is it in the case of a tie? How can I get all the keys to the highest value?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could run the following, for example:

```
max_value = max(scores.values())
keys = [ i for (i,v) in scores.iteritems() if v == max_value ]
```

"keys" would now hold all the keys which correspond to the maximum value.

Comment: That's probably the best way.

Comment: Wouldn't `keys = [i for (i,v) in scores.items() if v == max_value]` be a tad faster ?

Comment: Nice. In fact, using scores.iteritems(), the loop over the dictionary runs over twice as fast. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

The `max` function returns one value. You could use something like this:

```
key = max(scores, key=scores.get)
keys = [k for k in scores if scores[k] == scores[key]]
```

Edit: fixed

Comment: That won't work. `max_value` will contain the *key* that is associated with the/a maximum value, not the value itself.

Comment: I think you mean `if scores[k] == scores[max_value]` I'm pretty sure the `max` function returns the index of the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
scores = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=5)
maxscr = max(scores.values())

maxscrs =  [scr for scr in scores if scores[scr]== maxscr]
```

gives:

```
 ['e','f']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max_value = max(scores, key=scores.get)
keys = [score for score in scores if scores[score] == max_value]
```